# not able to send email using gmailsender in signed app

Tags: android

I am using the gmailsender to send email in my app. I followed the link below [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)

I am however facing a strange issue. While testing it in eclipse, everything goes fine. When I get my project signed(I am also using proguard while generating APK) and then install the corresponding ready=to-upload APK on my phone, the gmail sender does not seem to work. There is no error message thrown, but email does not get sent to the address specified. Same thing works very well then I test it in developer version. But while signing, compressing(using proguard)and exporting to an APK file, the same gmailsender functionality does not work.
I am not using any attachments in the email.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your google developer [console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)

and click on "API Access" on the left menu to generate the right api access token for your Android application.

Comment: I have created a new Key for Android apps (with certificates) as mentioned there. How do I use this key now in my android app?

Comment: Also under "Services" I don't see any email services. So do I need to generate key for using gmail in my app?